# How to set API key for google maps distance matrix API in java script to know quota limits and usage

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I need to trace `google maps` usage and quota limits for every API used in my project but i don't know how to set a API key in google maps distance matrix API(java script).

```
 var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {

                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                document.getElementById("TxtDistanceAprox").value = distance;
                document.getElementById("TxtTripTime").value = duration;
                PlaceMarkers(driverstatus, map);
                Vehiclerate();

            }
            else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script> Your api key is attached with google map script url.

Comment: Thanks @AnkushJain got the answer change in script source "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>"